# Problema conectividad entre maquinas virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

tengo un problema que no se donde esta realmente el error, si es una falla de virtualbox o que, tengo 2 maquinas virtuales en oracle vm virtualbox una que corre kali linux, y otra windows 10, ambas estan conectadas en una red nat(estoy aprendiendo pentesting), ambas pc tienen internet y diferente ip, pero aunque estan en la misma red nat no se detectan entre si, al ejecutar el comando `netdiscover -r ex:10.0.2/24` me aparece la interfaz grafica como que busca pero instantaneamente me tira que termino la busqueda y no aparece ningun resultado, ninguna otra ip nada, alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema, gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat] tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo o configuración de tu red, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta desactivar los firewalls para ambas maquinas

> En linux desde la terminal

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

> En windows desde CMD

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile state off
```

Comment: el problema era que cuando instale ambos SO los configure para que no se detecten entre otros dispositivos ni en red publica ni privada, ahora cambie la configuracion, pero al SO de kali no lo cambie ya que no se como cambiar esa configuracion para que sea detectada por otros dispositivos en la misma red(privada), aun sigo sin poder detectarlos, quiero probar si haciendo que kali sea detectado por otros equipos se arregla el problema, gracias por tu ayuda de igual manera